# How to get the sum directly with one number?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm a beginner for tableau. I want to get the direct numbers for each row, but i get the number which are separate, how can i achieve this?

I've tried the sentence like:count("Implemented"), but I don't get the result I want.

For example, for the 1st row I want 3 10 10

not 111  10  112111111

Here is [worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qNP5.png).

My code:

[image: my code]

EDIT :

here is the photo for [implementation opportunities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDlZk.png)

As you can see, the status is related to the date, I think maybe it causes the records which are counted 1by1.

Now the situation is that:  i create the code which is related to the date,  if i remove this from mark,  it will cause the problem   (the code is related to the date),   but if i leave it,  the system will always count it one by one.  My code is not perfect but i can't find another one which can replace it.....

EDIT  2:

in short,what i want is the sum of the remaining opportunity:10
[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgAXg.png)

Comment: can you share tableau workbook?

Comment: you mean worksheet?

Comment: yes.........................

Comment: i have the link for the photo ,which is called worksheet.can you see it?

Comment: Yes I can see it as a image, but it is difficult to tell seeing the image where it was wrong, instead if you attach a workbook then I can see the code and can help changing the workbook

Comment: I dont know how to attach this my bro...my level of the account isnot that high,can you see my new edit?if it doesn't work,can you leave me your contact so that i can give you more information?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: When posting questions, please use upper case letters as per the usual rules for English, and use a speller checker. Questions here are for future readers, not just for question authors, and we're keen that Stack Overflow does not get used as a chatroom.

Comment: remove day(end date) in filter and check?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `DAY` from Mark shelf. That detail is producing those separations.

Comment: thank you for your answer,but when i remove the date from the marks,the results are wrong,i don't know why does it happen

Comment: are you using that Day part in any of your calcualtions?

Comment: why the results are wrong? Do you need a total count, or count distinct (`COUNTD`)?

Comment: i need a total number,just like i mentioned above, if i remove the day in the mark,there is only one status....

Answer (score 0):

Attaching a workbook with numbers similar to (but not exact due to proprietary issues) is almost always advised. You will get the right answer a lot sooner than just screenshots.

In any case, it seems as if the measure portion of the visualization is properly being summed by the date.  Try selecting the measure, and manually selecting "sum" from the menu drop down. [Here is a link for more detail.](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_aggregation_aggregatingdata.html)

Secondly, you can play around with table calculations. [Click this link](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/calculations_tablecalculations_quick.html) and read up on option 3.

Comment: Thank you,i tried what you told me but it seemed that it didn't work..now the situation is that:i create the code which is related to the date,if i remove this from mark,it will cause the problem,but if i leave it,the system will always count it one by one.My code is not perfect but i can't find another one which can replace it